# Biber and Biblatex sorting entries wrong when ids are being used

Tags: biblatex, biber

I'm using biblatex with backend=biber to write a document. For simplicity I use "ids" in certain entries in my bibliography but not in others. The problem I am having is that entries with "id" get sorted afterwards even though they should be sorted in order of appearance (sorting=none)

I'm using version of biber: 2.11

In other words, in the example below I am getting,

```
   This should appear as 1: [2]
   and this should appear as 2: [1]
```

When it should be

```
   This should appear as 1: [1]
   and this should appear as 2: [2]
```

Any ideas?

My example.tex

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, sorting=none, style=numeric-comp, firstinits=true, maxnames=4, uniquename=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{example.bib}
\begin{document}
    This should appear as 1:~\cite{id:peskin}
    and this should appear as 2:~\cite{Ellis:1991qj}
\end{document}
```

And my example.bib file:

```
@book{Peskin:1995ev,
  ids          = {id:peskin},
  author       = {Peskin, Michael E. and Schroeder, Daniel V.},
  title        = {An Introduction to quantum field theory},
  publisher    = {Addison-Wesley},
  address      = {Reading, USA},
  year         = {1995},
  url          = {http://www.slac.stanford.edu/~mpeskin/QFT.html},
  isbn         = {9780201503975},
  SLACcitation = {%%CITATION= INSPIRE-407703;%%}
}
@book{Ellis:1991qj,
  author         = {Ellis, R. Keith and Stirling, W. James and Webber, B. R.},
  title          = {QCD and collider physics},
  publisher      = {Cambridge University Press}, 
  year           = {1996},
  pages          = {1-435},
  SLACcitation   = {%%CITATION = CMPCE,8,1;%%}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This seems to be one of the rare occasions where you need to run Biber twice. I get the expected output if I run LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX. Unfortunately, there was no Biber re-run request, maybe that could be improved... What versions of `biblatex` and Biber are you using?

Comment: That actually solve the problem! If you put it in the form of an answer I'll accept it!
I had to run "pdflatex & biber & pdflatex & biber & pdflatex" to get the correct answer. I'll add the version of latex to the question for reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of the rare occasions where Biber has to be run twice to obtain the expected result. A compilation would run

- LaTeX
- Biber
- LaTeX
- Biber
- LaTeX
- LaTeX

The additional run is necessary because the id alias needs to be resolved properly.

In fact the first LaTeX run after the first Biber run requests a second Biber run, but if you run LaTeX instead that warning disappears... I opened a ticket about this (https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/778), but I'm not sure what can be done here.